# Partially working AJAX that writes form input to text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This script is supposed to take the users input in an HTML form and use AJAX to write that input to a text file via PHP. When I run this code, however, I get two alerts, first 'error' then 'complete' (form the .fail and .always functions in AJAX) which leads me to believe that the problem is in the information being sent back by PHP.

```
<?php 
$fileHandle = fopen('emailList.txt', 'a') OR die ("Can't open file\n");
$email=$_POST['email'];
var_dump($email);
$result = fwrite ($fileHandle, "$email; \n");
fclose($fileHandle);
echo (!$result)? "error" : $result;
die;
?>
```

Where 'email' is the name of the text input of the form.

But in case the PHP is correct, I'll put the HTML and javascript here as well:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="emailSubmitSidebar" placeholder=" Your Email">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submitButton" id="subscribeButton">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var input = $('.emailSubmitSidebar').val();
        var subscribeButton = $('#subscribeButton');

        subscribeButton.click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'emailform.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {email: $("input[name=email]").val()},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert("success!")
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                alert("complete");
            })
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What response code and header information are you getting? You can use developer tools for each browser or firebug to figure that out. Also, you could try wrapping your PHP in a try catch statement and return the caught error as a string.

Comment: I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " and it turned out I had forgotten a semicolon... (after alert("success!")). Thanks!